# Show a nickname on new line after a user add reaction

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am trying to show user Discord.Tag (or nickname) after the user's click reaction, using the discord API.

In my code, Discord.tag is just being overwritten by the user who last clicked on reaction. Users can be ±30.

This is what i want:

[image: Heading]

My Code:

```
private async Task OnReactionAdded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> arg1, ISocketMessageChannel arg2, SocketReaction arg3)
{
    var User = arg3.User.Value as SocketGuildUser;
    ulong MessageID = 843502656663715860;
    if (arg3.MessageId != MessageID) return;
    if (arg3.Emote.Name != "✅") return;

    var message = (RestUserMessage)await arg2.GetMessageAsync(MessageID);
    await message.ModifyAsync(x =>                                    // Edit message
    {
        var exampleField = new EmbedFieldBuilder()
            .WithName("New Users")
            .WithValue($"User: {arg3.User.Value} \n " +               //overwritting user
                       $"User: {arg3.User.Value} \n ");               //
        x.Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .AddField(exampleField)
            .Build();
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it creates a new instance of EmbedFieldBuilder() whenever it creates the content for the field. Are you able to create a builder that starts off with the content of what is already on the field and just append the new users reaction onto it?

Comment: Get the embed from the message and modify that instead of crating a new embed. When you retrieve the embed, you can call `ToEmbedBuilder` to convert it to an embed builder so it can be edited. Simply edit the field value by appending the new user. Then you can call modify on the message and give it your modified embed.

Comment: @Anu6is The problem is that I don't know how to get the embed from the message. I tried `var emd = message.Embeds`, it returns the `Length = 1`. In debug mode I found the message value: [Debug](https://i.imgur.com/5v4clNI.png)

Comment: `Embeds` is a collection. Simply get the first item in the collection. `message.Embeds.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem a little differently. Here is the code the user's add reaction

```
private async Task OnReactionAdded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> arg1, ISocketMessageChannel arg2, SocketReaction arg3)
{
     var User = arg3.User.Value as SocketGuildUser;
     if (arg3.MessageId != 843502656663715860) return;
     if (arg3.Emote.Name != "✅") return;
     var message = (RestUserMessage)await arg2.GetMessageAsync(843502656663715860);
     var newUser = message.Embeds.FirstOrDefault().Fields.FirstOrDefault().Value;
     if (newUser.Contains((arg3.User.Value).ToString())) return;
     await message.ModifyAsync(x => 
     {
          var exampleField = new EmbedFieldBuilder()
                 .WithName("New Users")
                 .WithValue($"{newUser}\n{arg3.User.Value}");
          x.Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                  .AddField(exampleField)
                  .Build();
      });
}
```

And bonus, if user remove reaction

Code

```
private async Task OnReactionRemoved(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> arg1, ISocketMessageChannel arg2, SocketReaction arg3)
{
    if (arg3.MessageId != 843502656663715860) return;
    if (arg3.Emote.Name != "✅") return;
    var User = arg3.User.Value.ToString();
    var message = (RestUserMessage)await arg2.GetMessageAsync(843502656663715860);                                                                        
    var newUser = message.Embeds.FirstOrDefault().Fields.FirstOrDefault().Value;
    string newValue = "";
    if (newUser.Contains((arg3.User.Value).ToString()))
    {
        newValue = newUser.Replace($"\n{arg3.User.Value}", " ");
    }
    await message.ModifyAsync(x => 
    {
        var exampleField = new EmbedFieldBuilder()
                .WithName("New Users")
                .WithValue($"{newValue}");
        x.Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .AddField(exampleField)
                .Build();
    });
}
```